# Are performance metrics for Azure AD OAuth endpoints available?

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-log-analytics, azure-monitoring

I'm using Azure AD for an OAuth Client Credentials flow, including hitting this endpoint to get a token:
`https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/token`

I have a requirement to measure the performance of this call (as in how long it took to return a response) - are such timings made available in Azure?

I've looked in the various AAD logs - Audit logs, all the logs which you can send to Log Analytics (AuditLogs, SignInLogs, NonInteractiveUserSignInLogs, etc.), 'Usage & insights'.

When I look in the general Metrics blade and 'Select a scope', searching for a Resource type of 'Azure AD Metrics' doesn't return anything to select.

Is it possible to find such details, and if so where do I look?

Comment: The `OAuth Client Claims flow` you mean [client credential flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow)?

Comment: Sorry yes, Client Credentials - I'll update the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usage of client credential flow will not be recorded in the logs, if you want to measure the performance of this call like how long it took to return a response, you could send a request in the postman, it will give the information.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Joy.  Unfortunately as it's the client and not us hitting this endpoint we can't measure it from the caller's perspective, so we'll have to work something else out.  I'll give it a day or two in case anyone else knows of a way to do it before accepting this answer.

Comment: @GrantCrofton Actually if you are using some user-involved flow like [auth code flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-on-behalf-of-flow), the usage record should be included in the log, but I am not sure if the response time will be included, have not looked into it before.